# Using ajax in aspx page rather than reloading the whole page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am a very junior programmer in aspx, and I need help.

I have currently one aspx page. This page contains 3 tables.

The first table is the main table, which contains rows with data. When you click on one row, the other 2 table shows up with the details. Below is the picture.

[image]

This is working fine with the window.location code.

I want this project to upgrade with ajax. When you click on one row, show the data, but without reloading the page.

What would be the best practice, dissable to 3 aspx page? If anyone can provide a good example/practice article that would be great.

The onclick method for every row:

```
 var table = document.getElementById("table1");
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            var customerId = getParameterByName('customerid');
            var table1Index = '<%= (FindHeaderIndex("table1Columns", "Agreement_NUM")) %>';
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) { //length - 1 to avoid footer row
                var currentRow = table.rows[i];
                var createClickHandler =
                    function (row) {
                        return function () {
                            var table1Number = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[table1Index].innerHTML;
                            window.location = "Project.aspx" + "?" + "customerid=" + customerId + "&" + "table1Number=" + table1Number;
                        };
                    };
                currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
            }
```

get parameters

```
 function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
```

body

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="mainPanel"></asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" Height="40%" ID="detailsPanel"></asp:Panel>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="errorLabel" CssClass="errorMessage" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something I've used before.  Instead of simply reloading the page, you can "ajaxify" the process by making an Ajax call to load the new page state and then parse that, grab any updated Html and update the current view.

Add this function to your script...

```
function updateElementsById(newDataUrl) {
    if (arguments.length < 2) return;
    var $container = $("<div/>");
    $container.load(newDataUrl, function() {
        var idList = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        idList.forEach(function(id) {
            $(id).html($div.find(id).html());
        });
    });
}
```

Now, in order to update tables 2 and 3 (I'll assume the ids of table2 and table3) you'd call the function like this...

```
var url = "Project.aspx?customerid=" + customerId + "&table1Number=" + table1Number;

updateElementsById(url, "#table2", "#table3");
```

That should be enough to get you working.  Let me know if you have any issues.

Incidentally, this is a nice-and-easy bit of a hack really.  If you want a real solution then you should look at returning data to Ajax calls, but that means making some sort of API to serve the data you need.  You could take the current code that gets the relevant data and put that in a class that does all your data access, and then use that class in the page and also have a controller or generic handler return the data for you.

There are lots of alternatives.  It depends on your needs and the use case.

Comment: hi! thanks for the help. i pasted your code into mine, and got this error: arguments.slice is not a function

Comment: Sorry - my bad.  You can't use slice on arguments.  I've modified it now - it should be good to go :)